# How does Chrome implement its tabs?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, google-chrome

I am working on a small application, which I can do in either WinForms or WPF.  I'd like to replicate the tab control a la Chrome.  However, I am not sure how to get the tabs into the window border like Chrome does.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating tabs in the Windows titlebar area in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526896/creating-tabs-in-the-windows-titlebar-area-in-c) <- unfortunately the accepted answer in that question isn't great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `FormBorderStyle` (WinForms) or `WindowStyle` (WPF) to `None`, then draw your own titlebar with tabs on it.

To get glass, you need to [use the DWM API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/AeroGlassForms.aspx).

Alternatively, you can handle the `WM_NCPAINT` message.

Comment: Chrome uses GDI+ to create the tabs??

Comment: @dc1 If I recall correctly Chrome uses an in house drawing library to render it's own windows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a window without borders and draw your own border-like tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not have window style, the buttons are also not standard, that why this look like a tab in window border.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = ...

form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
```